# audioserver error prevent android ROM to boot

Tags: android

I've built an unofficial version of POSP for Xperia X (suzu) but I'm stuck at boot logo.
I've extract the log during the failing boot and the main error present is this

```
555   555 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 555 (audioserver), pid 555 (audioserver)
```

[here](https://hastebin.com/ahalunusum.coffeescript) you can find the complete tombstone for the error.

Someone as any idea what actually is this error? because I'm clueless on how to even start to solve it.

Thanks a lot.

Addendum:
digging about the problem I've tried to change the framework/av project using the aosp one (because the aosp 10 build with the same tree work without problem) but the issue still remains.

Maybe a sepolicy problem?

Hoping someone could shed some light. Thanks